# Disable keyUp/Down Support in Primereact Input Number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, primereact

Is there a way to remove default KeyUp/KeyDown event listners from primereact Input Nubmer;
Ps: i want event to be propagated and treated by the parent
[image]

Comment: according to [docs](https://primereact.org/inputnumber/) it doesnt look like you can do this. unless you can view the source code and then using the html tree to disable the key event listener, so some hacking is needed.

Comment: i want to disable the default Behavior, but let the event propagate to the parent :(